Failed to apply plugin class 'org.gradle.plugins.ide.idea.IdeaPlugin'
Description:-
I am trying to upgrade the android project as per API 34
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-all.zip
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.2'
But when i am trying to sync this after upgrading to 8.0. The android studio gives error like this
Failed to apply plugin class 'org.gradle.plugins.ide.idea.IdeaPlugin'.
Cannot run Project.afterEvaluate(Action) when the project is already evaluated.
Project should upgrade as per the gradle 8.0 and latest
